# how to set a specific id to table's cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and i want to set a specific id to every `td`'s in my table. For more explanation:

---

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to make that table like this via Jquery:

```
<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td" id="td1"></td>
    <td class="td" id="td2"></td>
    <td class="td" id="td3"></td>
    <td class="td" id="td4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td" id="td5"></td>
    <td class="td" id="td6"></td>
    <td class="td" id="td7"></td>
    <td class="td" id="td8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please help me to do this, Thank you all.

Comment: is it like sequential `td1, td2, td3 ..` ??

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Yes it is.

Comment: please check, have put an answer in

Comment: What did you try that isn't working? It is expected that you show your code attempts to solve your own issue when asking questions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? You can use `each()` which will give you the element and the index.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myTable td').each((i, e) => {
    $(e).attr('id', `td${(i + 1)}`);
    $(e).html(`td${(i + 1)}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) in this instance.

Here's the jQuery method:

```
$('td').each((i, cell) => {
  $(cell).attr("data-id", `td${i + 1}`);
});
```

And here's the equally succinct vanilla JS method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell, i) => {
  cell.dataset.id = `td${i + 1}`;
});
```

If you have multiple tables loop over them like you do with the cells, and then loop over that table's cells. Here's a vanilla JS method that creates a table id and uses that together with the cell id to create a data attribute like: `td2.1` for cell 1 in table 2. If you run the snippet and inspect the tables elements you can see this effect.

```js
// Grab all the tables
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');

// Iterate over the tables
tables.forEach((table, tableIndex) => {

  // Create the tableId
  const tableId = tableIndex + 1;

  // Add a table id for each table
  table.dataset.id = `table${tableId}`

  // Grab the cells in each table
  const cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');

  // Iterate over each table cell
  cells.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {

    // Create the cellId
    const cellId = cellIndex + 1;

    // Add the cell id
    cell.dataset.id = `td${tableId}.${cellId}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="myTable"><tr class="tr"><td class="td">1</td><td class="td">2</td><td class="td">3</td><td class="td">4</td></tr><tr class="tr"><td class="td">5</td><td class="td">6</td><td class="td">7</td><td class="td">8</td></tr></table>
<table class="myTable"><tr class="tr"><td class="td">1</td><td class="td">2</td><td class="td">3</td><td class="td">4</td></tr><tr class="tr"><td class="td">5</td><td class="td">6</td><td class="td">7</td><td class="td">8</td></tr></table>
```

And the jQuery version:

```js
// Iterate over the tables
$('table').each((tableIndex, table) => {

  // Create the tableId
  const tableId = tableIndex + 1;

  // Add a table id for each table
  $(table).attr('data-id', `table${tableId}`);

  // For each cell in the table
  $('td', table).each((cellIndex, cell) => {

    // Create the cellId
    const cellId = cellIndex + 1;

    // Add the cell id
    $(cell).attr('data-id', `td${tableId}.${cellId}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable"><tr class="tr"><td class="td">1</td><td class="td">2</td><td class="td">3</td><td class="td">4</td></tr><tr class="tr"><td class="td">5</td><td class="td">6</td><td class="td">7</td><td class="td">8</td></tr></table>
<table class="myTable"><tr class="tr"><td class="td">1</td><td class="td">2</td><td class="td">3</td><td class="td">4</td></tr><tr class="tr"><td class="td">5</td><td class="td">6</td><td class="td">7</td><td class="td">8</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop each instance of `.myTable`and then find all `td` and loop them. I've removed ES6 features.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Loop each table
  $('.myTable').each(function (i, e) {
  
    // Loop each TD in the table
    $(e).find('td').each(function (i, e) {
    
      // Set the attribute id
      $(e).attr('id', 'td' + (i + 1));
      
      // Write it out for debugging
      $(e).html('td' + (i + 1));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="myTable">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
    <td class="td"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```